# Cannot read property "search" of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I'm trying to make a script work that uses theYoutube API, i put in a keyword, youtube api finds video -> script takes first result and returns VideoID. Now my problem is that the search function doesn't get triggerd when I press my submit button. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this? This is the code;

html

```
<script src="assets/js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <center>
    <h3 class="h3">KJKerstborrel - Muziekrequest</h3>
        <div class="input">
            <form name="muziek" action="succes/index" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="artiest"  name="artiest" placeholder="Gewenste artiest" /><br>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="nummer"  name="nummer" placeholder="Gewenst nummer" required/><br>
                <button style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-success" onClick="search()" type="button">Deze wil ik horen!</button><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

JS

```
    // Your use of the YouTube API must comply with the Terms of Service:
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms
var YT = 'undefined';

// Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
function showResponse(response) {
    YT = response;

    document.getElementById('VideoURL').value = YT.items[0].Id.VideoID;
}

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
    search();
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    // See http://goo.gl/PdPA1 to get a key for your own applications.
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyD49-XZ2JV7Rws3KDM2T7nA56Jbi-O7djY');
}

function search() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'id',
        q: document.getElementById("artiest").value + " - " + document.getElementById("nummer").value,
    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes in the JS and i added a field in the html to display the video id.

The html file:

```
<script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <center>
    <h3 class="h3">KJKerstborrel - Muziekrequest</h3>
        <div class="input">
            <form name="muziek" action="succes/index" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="artiest"  name="artiest" placeholder="Gewenste artiest" /><br>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="nummer"  name="nummer" placeholder="Gewenst nummer" required/><br>
                <button style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-success" onClick="search()" type="button">Deze wil ik horen!</button><br>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="VideoURL"  name="VideoURL" placeholder="VideoURL"/><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

The JS file:

```
// Your use of the YouTube API must comply with the Terms of Service:
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms
var YT = 'undefined';

// Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
function showResponse(response) {
    YT = response;
    // changed: namegiving
    document.getElementById('VideoURL').value = YT.items[0].id.videoId;
}

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
    //search();    // changed.
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    // See http://goo.gl/PdPA1 to get a key for your own applications.
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyD49-XZ2JV7Rws3KDM2T7nA56Jbi-O7djY');
}

function search() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var qVar = document.getElementById("artiest").value
             + " - "
             + document.getElementById("nummer").value;
    // changed. added: type
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        type: 'video',
        part: 'id',
        q: qVar
    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i followed your example and i got the same error but then followed this tutorial and i was able to make a successful call

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples