# Upload video to Youtube with one single button using javascript

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

So I usarly make livestream videos on other livestream services, and I need to make little video to youtube  for I'm online on twitch or anywhere else every time, really noing thing.
My plan is:
I rendered out a video, stored it somewhere for example, on my server, and on a page what I created, I click for  the upload button and after that the video is would be uploaded to Youtube.
Just to be we clear:
I don't whant file input, or anything else on the page, just a upload button, which upload a video from a fix path.
I searched my ass on my Google, and looks like I late this question a littlebit, becouse Youtube API v2- was "Dircet upload" opportunity, but the new version just don't.
I looked javascript example on google github page, but it's just too complex for me.
I tryed modified javascript source from this:

```
$('#button').attr('disabled', true);
```

to this:

```
this.uploadFile("http://neocsatblog.info/embeds/Hammerfall.mp4".get(0).files[0]);
```

But I get this erorr:

> upload_video.js:163 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files'
>   of undefined
>   Also I viewed some articles on stackoverflow about this subject:

1. [I want to upload a video from my web page to youtube by using javascript youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683240/i-want-to-upload-a-video-from-my-web-page-to-youtube-by-using-javascript-youtube)
2. [How do I upload a video to Youtube directly from my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242851/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-directly-from-my-server)

But I not realy get that answer what I need.
At this point I gived up, I need help for I can move forward.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492954/youtube-data-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setapikey-of-undef / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614965/cannot-read-property-search-of-undefined

Comment: this totally differend questions